# Doubt about Rigged election in South Korea

Tags: probability

South Korea’s 21st legislative elections were held on 15 April 2020.

There are two types of early voting systems in Korea. One is to vote to candidate in your own local area. The other is to vote to candidate in other local area where your address is registered but you cannot go. I will call each of this A and B.

This is the result of early voting in Yeonsu District. 
I brought this data from National Election Commission.

As you see, if we divide B by A, we have almost same result, 0.39. Not only in this area, but also in other areas, certain numbers appear like 0.29, 0.26 and so on. 
My question is that is it possible from a stochastic point of view?

[image: early voting rate]

Comment: I am Korean. This doesn't just happen in one area. There are more than 40 places where the percentage of all candidates' votes converge on a particular constant. I used a translator because I am not good at English. I hope you'd understand.

Comment: May I know the source for the data you have presented above?

Comment: I am Korean.
Here is the Early-votiong votes ratio.
In the case of Incheon, the total number of votes cast by the Democratic Party and the Future Party is 572,546.
also, the two parties won 363,372 and 209,174 votes, respectively.
A.(the votes of each party)/(the total votes)
Calculated by formula A, the following specific values are given: Democratic Party : 363,372 / 572,546 = 0.6346 Future Party : 209,174 / 572,546 = 0.3653 How can these three big cities have such a uniform values?
Besides this, there are countless other statistically strange values.
What do you think of this result?

Comment: Is there a reason to believe those cities should have different political leanings? With such large samples, it doesn't seem odd to me that they'd produce similar results, if they represent the same demographics in different locations.

Comment: I broght data from here. http://info.nec.go.kr/m/ You can translate it by using Chrome.

Comment: Seoul, Gyeonggi, Incheon are not a single district. They are big cities in capital area, consist of several districts. When we sum up all the votes in each districts, we can get almost same results, 63:36. Try to think this thing happens in your country. Is it possible?

Comment: @shy462 In the 2012 United States election, the Democratic candidate for the Senate received 53.8% of the vote in California, 53.6% in Minnesota, 53.1% in New Jersey, 53.2% in Ohio, and 53.7% in New Mexico. These aren't single districts either. They're states with millions of people each and very different cultures. Nevertheless, when you sum up those people, you get almost the same results.

Comment: @shy462 Apologies, the above figures were for the 2018 election.

Comment: @shy462 You appear to be comparing the vote totals of two cities (Seoul and Incheon) with the vote totals of a province containing many cities (Gyeonggi). For any dataset large enough to be subdivided in multiple statistically-meaningful ways, you are basically guaranteed to find some combination of those subdivisions that happen to look similar by pure chance. (And this isn't even getting into the fact that political parties conduct their own internal polling and tailor their message to have safe margins in their constituent regions, like cities.)

Comment: @shy462 Perhaps counter-intuitively, it's less surprising to see something like that when summing up the results of many districts. Consider the following thought experiment: Take the national result and then distribute districts randomly in two groups (e.g: one random precinct from Seoul together with a random precinct from Incheon, etc.): Wouldn't you expect the results to be about the same in both halves of the country? What would really be odd is smaller scale districts all reporting very similar results.

Comment: @shy462 The question you need to ask yourself is: do you still find many of these coincidences if you compare "like with like" (for example, cities with other cities)? If so, how many such coincidences would you expect from pure chance alone? Do you observe significantly more coincidences than you would expect from pure chance alone? Answering this question requires you to have a good model of the distribution of random variables that produce election results, which is, of course, very difficult.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @kim.  These are not answers by SE's standards.  At best, you are providing other information about the phenomenon.  The "Your answer" field should only be used to post stand-alone answers to the question at the top of the thread.  Be aware that if you keep posting such answers, the system may automatically ban you from being able to post any answers at all, and there won't be anything we can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

If the voters are split randomly between A  and B, it would not be surprising that their voting behaviour be the same and (given the large numbers involved) that the proportions of votes to each party under each regime A  and B were also nearly the same.

However, I would expect that elder people with less mobility from their residence area, for instance, would fall mainly under regime A and youngsters (studying away from their homes, for instance) would fall under regime B. If elder people and youngsters vote differently (as would appear likely), I aggree with you that the result is surprising.

Answer (score 3):

I am not very familiar with how election results should look like, e.g how big is the variation and how much it would differ from the null hypothesis contingency table.

Looking the result, we can do a chi-sq test similar to what you have:

```
M = matrix(c(15797,6185,11335,4460,5296,2073),ncol=3)
chisq.test(M)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  M
X-squared = 0.052314, df = 2, p-value = 0.9742
```

If we ask the probability of get a result as close to the expected, i.e, a X-square lesser than 0.052314, it's 1 - 0.9742 = 0.0258. Normally we would do:

```
pchisq(0.052314,2)
[1] 0.02581787
```

However this is only 1 observation / experiment. Ideally you collect such statistics over many local areas and perform the same analysis, and ask if this result is a blip or there are indeed trends.

I can give a well known [example](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/csi-mendel), R.A Fisher noticed in Gregor Mendel's experimental data, for many experiments the number of seeds with a certain phenotype matches closely the expected. An exceptionally good fit of data to theory. He tested the probability of getting a chi square lesser than the observed for each experiment Mendel had, and postulated that if they are independent and followed the null hypothesis, the probability of getting an overall better result if all experiments are repeated would be 7/100000. [More details about the analysis in this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ss/1300108237)

Fisher even proposed:

> "Although no explanation can be expected to be satisfactory, it
>   remains a possibility among others that Mendel was deceived by some
>   assistant who knew too well what was expected. This possibility is
>   supported by independent evidence that the data of most, if not all,
>   of the experiments have been falsified so as to agree closely with
>   Mendel's expectations."

Reason for pointing out the above example is, even Fisher's analysis, it's still widely debated whether Mendel manipulated his data, because there are biological reasons that we still know little of. It goes beyond the statistics.

One cannot easily conclude from analysis of 1 election result that it is rigged. Even if you collect data over multiple areas, there are still many factors one need to consider, and take into account.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the point of doing the chi - squared test here in the example you have demonstrated? Thanks

Comment: When you have expected and observed numbers, we can calculate the chi-square Xsq, and find its quantile given degree of freedom, df. For a chi-square test, we normally ask what is the probability of observing a chi-square value greater than Xsq. However in this situation, we can ask the converse

Comment: "how close is the observed counts compared to observed" in comment above I take it to mean "how close is the observed counts compared to expected". If so, "expected" under what hypothesis? For there is no reason to expect that vote to different parties is independent of segmentation into A and B.

Comment: @StupidWolf If the counts where 1000x smaller, say `M = matrix(c(15,6,11,4,5,2),ncol=3)`, you would still get a pvalue ~ 1 but in such case the results would be much less impressive - or am I missing something?

Comment: @F.Tusell, yes you are right, it was a typo, expected under the hypothesis rows and columns probabilities are independent. If I understood you correctly, you mean it's not a very useful hypothesis to have, because chances are voting probabilities will not be equal across all classes. This I agree, there's no point in testing if you know there should be a difference. I am not very sure of A / B in the question above. I interpret it as voters who have different access to voting

Comment: @AuroraBorealis, there was a typo, i meant expected counts versus observed. Expected will in the example be P(type=A)*P(Party=Democratic) * total to give you counts for type A and party democratic